# Mysql query failure laying me

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Everything was working fine before I upgraded my mysql version on server.

But now it's giving error and shows query failure. I have changed nothing in code.

```
SELECT id,frequency,speed FROM signal where active='Y'
```

It's showing error in from clause.Why this happening ?

Comment: What exact error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you upgraded in  Mysql5.5 and `SIGNAL` is new [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) in Mysql5.5.
`Escape` your table name signal with **backticks(`)**  in query.

Try below :

```
 SELECT id,frequency,speed FROM `signal` where active='Y'
```

Answer (score 2):

`SIGNAL` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), apparently. Enclose it in backquotes.

```
SELECT id,frequency,speed FROM `signal` where active='Y'
```

Whenever I get an error I don't expect in the `FROM` clause or elsewhere when the query appears to be syntactically correct, I consult the reserved words list for something I wasn't aware was reserved (and I admit I wasn't aware `SIGNAL` was reserved until I checked the list).

A bit of research hasn't pinned down when [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) was added yet, but I suspect it was in MySQL 5.5.